# Replace empty value php, html

Tags: php, html, if-statement, echo

I'm having a little trouble with a line of code.

It's a price field and when no price is added I want it to output 'NO PRICE' instead it just outputs a space by default, here's the code,

```
<p class="post-price"><?php cp_get_price( $post->ID, 'cp_price' );?> </p>
```

I've tried this,

```
<p class="post-price"><?php cp_get_price( $post->ID, 'cp_price' ); echo 'NO PRICE'?> </p>
```

but that shows the NO PRICE all the time. I'm trying to only make it show when the cp_price value is empty.

If anyone could lend a hand i would much appreciate it.

UPDATE:

Full back-end code,

```
function cp_ad_loop_price() {
global $post;
if ( $post->post_type == 'page' || $post->post_type == 'post' )
    return;
?>
<div class="price-wrap">
    <span class="tag-head">&nbsp;</span><p class="post-price"><?php cp_get_price( $post->ID,     'cp_price' );?></p>
</div>

<?php
}
add_action( 'appthemes_before_post_title', 'cp_ad_loop_price' );
```

And front-end with no value,

```
<div class="price-wrap">
    <span class="tag-head">&nbsp;</span><p class="post-price">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

front-end with value,

```
<div class="price-wrap">
    <span class="tag-head">&nbsp;</span><p class="post-price">£500.00</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

cp_get_price function,

```
if ( !function_exists('cp_get_price') ) {
function cp_get_price( $postid, $meta_field ) {
    global $cp_options;

    if ( get_post_meta( $postid, $meta_field, true ) ) {

        $price_out = get_post_meta( $postid, $meta_field, true );
        $price_out = cp_price_format( $price_out );
        $price_out = cp_pos_currency( $price_out, 'ad' );

    } else {
        if ( $cp_options->force_zeroprice )
            $price_out = cp_pos_currency( 0, 'ad' );
        else
            $price_out = '&nbsp;';
    }

    echo $price_out;
}
}
```

Comment: Try `<?php cp_get_price( $post->ID, 'cp_price' ) ? echo 'NO PRICE' : ''; ?>`

Comment: Nope, that didn't work @Fred-ii-

Comment: Your function echoes instead of returning the output. Either edit the function to fix it, or use output buffering as a workaround. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060545/how-do-i-capture-the-result-of-an-echo-into-a-variable-in-php

Comment: Solved. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such a noob. All I needed was a push in the right direction. Thanks guys, now solved.

```
if ( !function_exists('cp_get_price') ) {
function cp_get_price( $postid, $meta_field ) {
global $cp_options;

if ( get_post_meta( $postid, $meta_field, true ) ) {

    $price_out = get_post_meta( $postid, $meta_field, true );
    $price_out = cp_price_format( $price_out );
    $price_out = cp_pos_currency( $price_out, 'ad' );

} else {
    if ( $cp_options->force_zeroprice )
        $price_out = cp_pos_currency( 0, 'ad' );
    else
        $price_out = '&nbsp;';
}

echo $price_out;
}
}
```

I edited this line

```
$price_out = '&nbsp;';
```

to look like this,

```
$price_out = 'NO PRICE';
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cp_get_price($post->ID, 'cp_price')` is returning an empty value instead of a space character, you can use the 'or' operator to return the first value that evaluates to `true`

```
<?
$var = cp_get_price($post->ID, 'cp_price');
echo $var || 'NO PRICE';
?>
```

UPDATE:

Since you are returning a space character, you can use this:

```
<?
$var = cp_get_price($post->ID, 'cp_price');
echo ($var == ' ') ? 'NO PRICE' : $var;
?>
```

Comment: It is returning a space character. Knew it wouldn't be simple lol

Comment: Nope, still returns just a space. :(

Comment: are you sure you're not talking about the space between `?>` and `</p>`?

Comment: Nope because when a value is added the space is replaced., I'll update my original post with the full code from front and back end.

Comment: ...you didn't add the relevant function

Comment: Sorry about that. I've included the correct function in the post

Comment: Solved. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo cp_get_price( $post->ID, 'cp_price' ) ? cp_get_price( $post->ID, 'cp_price' ) : 'NO PRICE'; ?>
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work, it showed NO PRICE on all price fields not just empty ones.